# Maximizing the cross entropy with techniques from the calculus of variations.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations, entropy

Define the cross-entropy of two probability distributions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ as

$$ H(p,q):=\int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} p(x) \log q(x) \, dx$$

Taking $p(x)$ as a fixed distribution I would like to find the equation that $q(x)$ has to satisfy to maximize this functional.

Assuming $q(x) \in C([-\infty, +\infty])$ I rewrite the problem using a Lagrange multiplier as

$$\max_{q(x) \in C([-\infty, +\infty])} \left( H(p,q) - \lambda \left( \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} q(x)  \, dx -1 \right) \right)$$

because I have to add in the condition that $q(x)$ integrates to one.

Now I wish to use the Euler-Lagrange equations, so I notice that $\frac{d}{dq} H(p,q) = p(x) / q(x)$ and that

$$ \frac{d}{dq} \left( H(p,q) -  \left( \int_{- \infty}^{+\infty} q(x)  \, dx -1 \right) \right) = p(x)/ q(x) -1$$

But I do not understand how to put this all together to find the equation that $q(x)$ has to satisfy, could someone explain this to me clearly?

Comment: Last equation suggests $p(x) = q(x)$?

Comment: @Nadiels how would I get that out of the system of equations the Lagrange multiplier generates? I have never used the multiplier in conjunction with a variational problem.